# APPNAME was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

This project is develop in Unity3d and build it to iOS.

This is my .cs file.

```
IEnumerator DownloadModel(string modelUrl)
    {
        isDownloading = true;
        // Wait for the Caching system to be ready
        while (!Caching.ready)
            yield return null;

        // Load the AssetBundle file from Cache if it exists with the same version or download and store it in the cache
        WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (modelUrl, 1);
        Debug.Log ("modelURL : " + modelUrl);
        while (!www.isDone) {
            progressText.text = "Progress : " + (www.progress * 100).ToString ("N0") + "%";
            Debug.Log("Download Progress : " + (www.progress * 100).ToString ("N0") + "%");
            yield return null;
        }

        yield return www;  

        isDownloading = false;

        if (www.error != null) {
            throw new UnityException ("WWW download had an error:" + www.error);
        }

        AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;

        downloadedObjectContainer = bundle.LoadAllAssets ();

        //              tempObj = Instantiate(downloadedObjectContainer[0]) as GameObject;
        //
        //              tempObj.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        isDownloading = false;

        // Unload the AssetBundles compressed contents to conserve memory
        bundle.Unload (false);
        // memory is freed from the web stream (www.Dispose() gets called implicitly)

        Debug.LogWarning ("START CALLING OUT OBJECT");
        if (downloadedObjectContainer[0] != null) {

            Debug.Log("Downloadable content count : " + downloadedObjectContainer.Length );

            currentDownloadedModel = Instantiate(downloadedObjectContainer[0]) as GameObject;
            Debug.Log("OBJECT INSTANTIATE.");

            currentDownloadedModel.transform.SetParent(this.transform);

            //set the ARContent and ImageTarget
            sic.setARContentAndMarker(currentDownloadedModel, ImageTarget);
            Debug.Log("CONTENT MARKER SET.");

            currentDownloadedModel.SetActive(true);

        }

        Debug.LogWarning ("COROUTINE FINISHED");
    }
```

and my "currentDownloadedModel" is declared at the top as GameObject.

```
public class cloudTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour{

     GameObject currentDownloadedModel;
```

When i build my App to Android, there is no problem at all. But once i build it in iOS, this error occurs

```
START CALLING OUT OBJECT

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 64)

Downloadable content count : 1

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 64)

MarcV2 was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
```

By the Debug.Log(), I found out that the problem occurs when I want to assign the currentDownloadedModel with the model i instantiate. Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks in advance.

Note : the "Script call optimization" at the unity player settings is set to "slow and safe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who also face this problem, try uncheck the "Strip Engine Code" at File > Build Settings > Player Settings (iOS).

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html